# Error while copying string to 2 dimensional character array

Tags: c++, string

Hi I want to maintain 100 strings. I am trying to copy each string into 2 dimensional character array. While compiling the program I am getting below error.

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char' to 'char [10]'
make[1]: *** [HPortClient.o] Error 1
```

Kindly let me know how I should copy this string into 2D char array. Below is the code snippet.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define MAX_DEVICE_NAMES    100
#define MAX_CHAR_NAME       10

struct HartShmDeviceData {
     char m_Name[MAX_DEVICE_NAMES][MAX_CHAR_NAME];

};
struct HartShmDeviceData *khdev;

void HPortClient::WriteDeviceListInShm(void)
{
    HartDevice *hDev;
    std::string tmp;
    int i=0;
    ITERATOR iter;
    for(iter = m_DeviceList.begin(); iter !=m_DeviceList.end(); ++iter)
    {
        hDev = *iter;
        const char *ptr=tmp.c_str();
        tmp = hDev->getName();
        ptr=tmp.c_str();

        strcpy(khdev->m_Name[i++],ptr); //Error in this line

        //khdev->m_Name[tmp.size()] = '\0'; // don't forget the terminating 0

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is on the `strcpy()` line and not on the next line where you try to terminate the string? The `strcpy()` line looks fine, the next line does not.

Comment: Where do you actually allocate memory for `struct HartShmDeviceData *khdev`? That is only a *pointer* after all.

Comment: Is your code in C or C++? If it's in C++ refrain from using `strcpy`.

Comment: My code is in C++. Kindly let me know how i can achieve this efficiently? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as you posted it in your question should compile correctly.

You probably want this:

```
  ...
  strcpy(khdev->m_Name[i],ptr);
  khdev->m_Name[i][tmp.size() + 1] = '\0';    // don't forget the terminating 0 
  i++ ;
}
```

`khdev->m_Name[tmp.size()] = '\0'` is clearly wrong because `khdev->m_Name[tmp.size()]` is not of type `char` but of type `char[MAX_CHAR_NAME]`

BTW `strcpy` already copies the  terminating zero, so the line `khdev->m_Name[i][tmp.size() + 1] = '\0';`is actually not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Michael, This solved my compilation problem but i am getting Segmentation fault while running the code at line khdev->m_Name[i][tmp.size() + 1] = '\0';

Comment: You must debug this yourself with a debugger or at least by inserting some printfs to see what's going on.

Comment: @Tushar you've allocated 'hDev ?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that you have to allocate `hDev` somehow (I guess in shared mem) you have to write

```
  strcpy(khdev->m_Name[i],ptr); // this looks fine to me
  khdev->m_Name[i++][tmp.size()] = '\0';
```

`'\0'` is a char and `khdev->m_Name[]` is an  array of char.

Comment: Thanks Oncaphillis. This also worked but getting segmentation fault while running the code at strcpy(khdev->m_Name[i],ptr);